# List is not persisting through updatemodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My generic list of products won't persist on the Post if I use UpdateModel but if I pass the ViewModel in as a parameter to my post action method it works? How can I get it to work through UpdateModel way?

I'm using asp.net fx3.5 mvc 1.0

**Model**

```
namespace PostingGenericListAndUpdateModel.ViewModels
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public ProductViewModel()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
            Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Widget 1", IsSelected = false });
            Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Widget 2", IsSelected = false });
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
<% for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   { %>
      <%= Model.Products[i].Name %>  <%= Html.CheckBox("Model.Products[" + i + "].IsSelected") %>
   <% } %>
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />           
   <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel();

    return View(model, new string[] { "OrderId", "Products" });
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)  //It will work if i accept the view model
{
    ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel();

    UpdateModel(model);

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason for this parameter 'string sender'. Why do you need it?

The usual way to do this is indeed, by accepting the view model as a parameter to your Post method.

This is the way MVC passes the information from the view to your controller.

Your Post method line should be:

```
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
```

Comment: I've changed it to accept the form collection. Why doesn't accepting a view model in the post method and updatemodel behave the same way as far as binding List<Product>?

Comment: can i use a custom model binder in this case so when updatemodel is called it would know how to handle it? i don't know? help!

Comment: You certainly can use custom model binder. This is the hard way to do it though.

Comment: BTW, while out of the scope, why are you using MVC1 and not MVC3?

Comment: Would it help in this case? i'm using vs2008 does that matter upgrading to mvc3? what would the custom model binder look like in this case?

Comment: Hmm it seems MVC3 needs VS2010, you can at least try MVC2 then. There were some improvements in the built in bindings.